# CultureInfo formatter wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using a ValueConverter in my WP7 app

```
public class Formatter : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            string formatterString = parameter.ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatterString))
            {
                return string.Format(culture, formatterString, value);
            }
        }
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Nothing to do - the Validation will handle the value correctness
        return value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I can then use to format a date like so,

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CreatedOn, Converter={StaticResource FormatConverter}, ConverterParameter=\{0:MMM d\, hh:mm tt\}}" Foreground="#ff1e3250" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" />
```

My Question is : How can I pass the user's current culture information?  I am aware of the ConveterCulture attribute that I can use in the Binding above but I don't want to pass in hard-coded values such as en-US.

I want to try and pass in the current culture that from CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property in System.Globalization.

I tried using something like:
x:Static global:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, but I get an error that Static is not defined

Pratik

Answer (score 0):

As you state, explicitly setting the `ConverterCulture` property on the binding would hard code you to a single region, which isn't ideal. If you don't specify the `ConverterCulture` property, then the value of the **culture** parameter in the `Convert` and `ConvertBack` methods uses the value of the [`Language`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.language%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property instead, but it's not clear from the documentation what the value would be if it wasn't explicitly set.

However, if you want to know what region the user is currently running under, then you can ignore the **culture** parameter completelt and use [`CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) instead.